# Python tkinter canvas get visible area during start up

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am having trouble getting tkinters canvas to give me the visible area during it's initialization, the reason I need to get the visible area during this time is that I need the coordinates to determine what to show the user immediately after creation.

The canvas will print it's area correctly after `__init__` by pressing the button, but not when the function is called after `.grid()` inside `__init__`

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk

class app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.vis_area_btn = tk.Button(self,text="Print Visible Area",
                                      command=self.prnt_vis_area)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self,bg="white",highlightthickness=0)
        self.vis_area_btn.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nswe")
        self.canvas.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="nswe")
        self.prnt_vis_area()

    def prnt_vis_area(self,event=None):
        #self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,1,1))
        x1 = self.canvas.canvasx(0)
        y1 = self.canvas.canvasy(0)
        x2 = self.canvas.canvasx(self.canvas.winfo_width())
        y2 = self.canvas.canvasy(self.canvas.winfo_height())
        print (x1,y1,x2,y2)

root = app()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating Tkinter window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411940/updating-tkinter-window)

Comment: @Rloqvist I'd argue that the possible duplicate you've suggested is unrelated to this issue, this is about updating a specific tkinter widget before hitting the mainloop of the Tk() window, the question you have suggested is a completely different issue about changing attributes of tkinter widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty simple fix.

tkinter has a function called `.update()` which is explained [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method):

> Processes all pending events, calls event callbacks, completes any pending geometry management, redraws widgets as necessary, and calls all pending idle tasks. This method should be used with care, since it may lead to really nasty race conditions if called from the wrong place (from within an event callback, for example, or from a function that can in any way be called from an event callback, etc.). When in doubt, use [update_idletasks](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#widget.Widget.update_idletasks-method) instead.

In short all you need to know is that adding `self.canvas.update()` before your call to `self.prnt_vis_area()` fixes your issue.

```
def __init__(self):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
    self.vis_area_btn = tk.Button(self,text="Print Visible Area",
                                  command=self.prnt_vis_area)
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self,bg="white",highlightthickness=0)
    self.vis_area_btn.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nswe")
    self.canvas.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="nswe")
    self.canvas.update() #here
    self.prnt_vis_area()
```